# Temp solutions to shower tiles

Tags: water, shower

I have a walk in shower. It looks like the tiles close to the floor inside the shower are coming off from the wall. Are there any temporary solutions to stop water from getting in until I redo things?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should  really stop using the shower and `redo` things right away.  But if you must, then fill it with bathroom sealant.

Comment: Do you know what’s behind the tile? It makes a difference if it’s an impermeable barrier like tar or kerdi…

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I removed the tile but not sure what I'm looking at. Just posted a new pic of the removed tile area.

Comment: I can’t tell from the pic. Does it look or feel like tar? (I was going to suggest you smell it, but it might be mold.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care how it looks, using some rubbing alcohol to clean the seams
well, then using a good bathtub caulk would be what I would do for a temporary fix.